# Set up a Xamarin UI Test getting error is incompatible with the Android SDK

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run a xamarin UI Test but I keep getting

**"The running adb server is incompatible with the Android SDK version in use by UITest"**

Googled it and cannot find answer I am using

- XamarinUITest= 3.0.7
- Nunit3TestAdapter 3.17
- Android SdK built tools  29.0.2 Set up
- Android_Home  = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Why Am I keeping getting the above error what am I Missing?

Where do I find instructions and what is compatible to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you have any directory in the androidSdK with a name "old" you should delete them and this fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link below to confirm your project is ready for automated UI testing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/

After that add UITest support to Xamarin.Forms apps. To enable the UITest code to reference controls, each control needs a unique identifier.

```
<Button x:Name="b" AutomationId="MyButton" Text="Click me"/>
<Label x:Name="l" AutomationId="MyLabel" Text="Hello, Xamarin.Forms!" />
```

For more details, please check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/xamarin-forms

Comment: Thanks for those link but they do not mention anything regarding what version of sdk you should use or if it should match with something else . My issue I cannot run the test I have in the first place.Whatever I do I keep getting that error.Wonder if is not the "real error"